# bash quote escaping change in 4.4

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am updating bash on our embedded platform from 4.1.9 to the latest (4.4.12), and I am seeing a behaviour change in this simple scenario of passing escaped arguments into a script.

Script /tmp/printarg:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "ARG |$*|"
```

And I invoke the script like this:

```
bash -c "/tmp/printarg \\"abc\\""
```

I've tried this on several platforms (native x86_64 Linux) running bash 4.3.42, as well as several embedded platforms (ARM and PPC) running bash 4.1.9 and 4.2.37, and all of these platforms report what I would expect:

```
38$ bash -c "/tmp/printarg \\"abc\\""
ARG |abc|
```

But, when I run this using bash 4.4.12 (native X86 or embedded platforms), I get this:

```
$ bash -c "/tmp/printarg \\"abc\\""
ARG |abc\|            <<< trailing backslash
```

And if I add a space in the command line between the second escaped quote and the ending quote, then I no longer see the extra backslash:

```
$ bash -c "/tmp/printarg \\"abc\\" "
ARG |abc |            <<< trailing space, but backslash is gone
```

This feels like a regression.    Any thoughts?   I also did try enabling the various compat options (compat40, compat41, compat42, compat43) with change.

Comment: I don't think "backquote" means what you think it means.

Comment: D'oh, sorry!     Make that "backslash".

Comment: Can you show the contents of /tmp/quotefail too?  Also, result of  `ls -l /bin/sh` may be of interest.

Comment: I get `ARG |abc\|` on Debian testing (buster) amd64 with bash 4.4.12(1)-release and /bin/sh set to dash (but that doesn't seem to matter; replacing printargs with a Perl program confirms)

Comment: BTW, if you mean your script to be run with `bash`, then a `/bin/sh` shebang is very poor form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bash -c "/tmp/printargs \\"abc\\""
```

Does not escape what you think it does. A backslash-backslash is an escaped backslash, handled by the calling shell — so that is the same as running:

```
/tmp/printargs \abc\
```

because the double-quotes are *not* escaped. You could have just written:

```
bash -c '/tmp/printargs \abc\'
```

I'm guessing you actually wanted:

```
bash -c "/tmp/printargs \"abc\""
```

which escapes the double quotes, passing a quoted "abc" to the bash -c.

(I'm guessing the different behavior you're seeing is different versions of bash handling the escaped nothing at end of input differently.)

Perl version of printargs (slightly improved behavior):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature qw(say);

for (my $i = 0; $i < @ARGV; ++$i) {
        say "$i: |$ARGV[$i]|";
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I actually wanted!    I was incorrectly thinking that the extra backslash escaped the quote through an additional level of shell.    When I changed my original code to use a single backslash, things worked as expected in both older and newer bash bash versions.   (Seems that the additional backslash was benign in older bash versions).  Thanks @derobert!

Comment: @SteveHein It wasn't actually quoted before — which maybe isn't an issue, or might be a major one. Depending on what you're doing (and in particular where that "abc" parameter comes from & how it is validated) that could be a security vulnerability allowing remote code execution. (And do note that just putting it in quotes may not be sufficient, depending on how "abc" is validated).

Answer (score 5):

```
bash -c "/tmp/printargs \\"abc\\""
```

Are you sure this is what you want to do? If you run that with `set -x` in effect, you'll see that the command that runs, is

```
bash -c '/tmp/printargs \abc\'
```

i.e. you're passing the shell a string that ends in a backslash. Your first quoted string contains an escaped backslash, then you have an unquoted `abc`, an escaped backslash, and then an empty quoted string. (Note how the syntax highlighting done by Stackexchange shows the `abc` is not quoted.)

The unquoted backslash at the end of input doesn't make much sense. A backslash either escapes the following character, or starts a continuation line, where it's deleted along with the following newline, like here:

```
$ bash -c $'echo "foo\\\nbar"'                                                                                                              
foobar
```

This case has neither. You're possibly trying to do either of these:

```
bash -c "/tmp/printargs \"abc\""
bash -c '/tmp/printargs "abc"'
```

Both of which produce the output `ARG |abc|`.

---

We can see the difference between shells with a bit simpler test:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION; echo abc\'
4.4.12(1)-release
abc\

$ ./bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION; echo abc\'
4.3.30(1)-release
abc

$ dpkg -l dash |grep ^i
ii  dash           0.5.8-2.4    amd64        POSIX-compliant shell
$ dash -c 'echo abc\'
abc\

$ dpkg -l zsh |grep ^i
ii  zsh            5.3.1-4+b2   amd64        shell with lots of features
$ zsh -c 'echo abc\'
abc
```

---

If I had to guess, I'd start looking for the source of the change in this change:

```
This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.4-alpha, and
the previous version, bash-4.3-release.

1.  Changes to Bash

cccc. Fixed a bug that resulted in short-circuited evaluation when reading
      commands from a string ending in an unquoted backslash, or when sourcing
      a file that ends with an unquoted backslash.
```

Comment: Thanks.   There are clearly better ways to do this.    I created this example to identify a problem that I was having in a more complex set of scripts where an arg is passed through multiple subscripts.

And there is probably a better way to rework the original script, but as I said, what I have here works without issue on a number of older bash versions.    My main exercise here is to move an existing platform to a new bash version (to eliminate ShellShock vulnerability).   So any incompatibilities that I see are a concern.

Comment: Are folks here saying that what I have should have never worked in the first place?

Comment: @SteveHein, if what you're doing is like the snippet in your question, you might want to check your quoting. And yes, I do think that the ending backslash makes no sense.

Comment: @ilkkachu Here is more info: [changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CWRU/changelog?id=a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071#n8246).

Comment: @PesaThe, right, makes sense if it's a fix to an actual bug. Though I'm not sure a fix that changes visible behaviour in other cases was the best one, but it's a corner case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain this one:

```
$ bash -c "/tmp/quotefail \\"abc\\" "
ARG |abc |            <<< trailing space, but backquote is gone
```

As @ilkkachu explained, with `set -x` we see how this is interpreted:

```
+ bash -c '/tmp/quotefail \abc\ '
```

Of course, "\a" is just "a", and "\ " is just " ", so the parameter /tmp/quotefail receives is "abc ", and the result:

```
ARG |abc |
```

In the first test, the backslash wasn't followed by anything, so it remained a backslash.